# An easier or quicker way to reference required assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

When you move a class from one assembly to another, you then also have to **re** reference one or more dlls. Visual Studio shows you the following error message:

> Error 56 The type TypeX is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. **You must add a reference to assembly** AssemblyA,
>   Version=1.0.93.609, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

This message suggests an automated solution is possible within small performance parameters because (1) it knows which assembly you need and (2) another project in the assembly already references it.

After manually referencing the 10nth assembly I started wondering, isn't there an easier way to transfer the assembly references from one project to another? It would be nice if I could right-click on the line where the error occurs, and select "***Reference assembly 'AssemblyA, Version=1.0.93, Culture=neutral' as referenced by Assembly X in the current solution.***"

NOTE: I am looking for a solution that does not rely on R# (resharper)

Answer (score 0):

Right mousse click on reference, and choose copy reference. 
past them to the target reference

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2013 ultimate, it doesn't have a "copy reference" option.